# How to 301 redirect static pagination to corresponding dynamic pagination

Tags: .htaccess, pagination

We use to have static pagination like 
http://www.ourwebsite.com/toys/page/19

Now we have changed it to have a dynamic pagination like http://www.ourwebsite.com/girl-toys?page=19

I have tried following redirection

> redirect 301 /toys/page/$ /girl-toys?page=$

But it's not working. I want to do it for every instances of such urls

Please let me know the rule for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^toys\/(.*)$ /girl-toys?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have done some mistake in url, the static url is http://www.ourwebsite.com/toys/19/ and its need to be redirected to http://www.ourwebsite.com/girl-toys?page=19 . Please provide the htaccess for the same.

Comment: I've corrected the rule. Please check them in .htaccess

Comment: Thanks Jarek, one more thing. the final url after redirection is  http://www.ourwebsite.com/girl-toys?page=19/ with a additional / , please let me know how to remove this extra /